# Invoke Shell Script from UI (with Java)

Tags: javascript, java, shell, rest

I have a Shell Script (which internally updates/makes some DB calls)
I want to invoke this shell script from my UI (Ember) code.

I would think there is no direct way of invoking this shell script from UI. But I use Java in the middle tier & also use REST (Spring app). So what are the ways of invoking this from UI (with AJAX calls)..I can write Controllers with endpoints & then invoke.

Any examples for reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just have some UI element trigger an AJAX request which tells Java to run the shell script. You can wait for it to finish and then respond with the output.

If the process takes more than a second or two, you might have to either increase the timeout of the AJAX request and your server (or it'll timeout before it returns). Alternatively (and even better), you could do it in two calls.

The first call would kick off the run and return some kind of ID.

A later call would pass back that ID and you would return the info from the shell script and/or some kind of status information.

Comment: Well...I completely understand the UI side of the piece...I am more interested in the server-side approach/handling...

Comment: There are a number of ways to run a command-line process on the server. Basically, you would just have the AJAX call kick it off, then track it somehow. There are any number of approaches. If you make your question more specific I might be able to give more specific help.

Comment: So my initiation point for running the shell script would be UI (web app)
How do I create the endpoint & from there how do I invoke the actual shell script ?

Comment: 1) Create a controller with an endpoint that does the actual running, 2) Have your web app call said endpoint, 3) If using Java to write the server-side stuff, check out the Process class for actually invoking it.